# Progress bar with html

Tags: html, css

I am making a progress bar, I have a problem wanting to show the gray background. I can't show it.

Could you please help me, I would also like not to use the current stylesheet and have my own that I can control.

```html
<html>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">

    <h2>Progress Bar</h2>
    <div class="w3-light-grey" style="background-color:grey !important;">
      <div class="w3-orange" style="height:24px;width:15%;float:left;border-radius:25px;"></div>
      <div class="w3-orange" style="height:24px;width:15%;float:left;border-radius:25px;"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="float:left">
      <p>Good!</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <p>Step 2 of 7</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[this is the design i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBti3.png)

Comment: You're asking how to "clear a float," which is what you should google for. The elements inside the progress bar have `float: left` which means they no longer take up height/width in the parent element. Adding `overflow: hidden` to the wrapping div is the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: Start by using the `<progress>` element, and then styling it from there.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the progress bar as you did with the inner orange bars. Without it (or any content inside the div), the height is set to 0 and is invisible.

```html
<html>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">

    <h2>Progress Bar</h2>
    <div class="w3-light-grey" style="color:grey !important; height: 24px;">
      <div class="w3-orange" style="height:24px;width:15%;float:left;border-radius:25px;">a</div>
      <div class="w3-orange" style="height:24px;width:15%;float:left;border-radius:25px;">a</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="float:left">
      <p>Good!</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <p>Step 2 of 7</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard HTML unless you have a good reason not to. There is a `<progress>` element defined in the standard.

> The progress element represents the completion progress of a task. The
> progress is either indeterminate, indicating that progress is being
> made but that it is not clear how much more work remains to be done
> before the task is complete (e.g. because the task is waiting for a
> remote host to respond), or the progress is a number in the range zero
> to a maximum, giving the fraction of work that has so far been
> completed.

```html
<label for="file">File progress:</label>

<progress id="file" max="100" value="70"> 70% </progress>
```